# AttributeError: module 'openstack.proxy' has no attribute 'Proxy'

Tags: python, openstack, opensuse, openstack-nova

I'm runing an Ussuri install on openSUSE 15.2. According the official install guide, the Keystone, Glance, and Placemente has run withou any bigger issues. But, when i try run any command with nova-manage, i have that message:

```
AttributeError: module 'openstack.proxy' has no attribute 'Proxy'
```

That message occurs at every comand with "nova-manage". Especially, i'm executing the step:

> Populate the nova-api database:

from the official guide, the command is:

```
su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage api_db sync" nova
```

Every log has that error, even the journalctl -xe if try to start the service without populate database.

The others services runs fine.

The full log is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/nova-manage", line 6, in <module>
    from nova.cmd.manage import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 48, in <module>
    from nova.cmd import common as cmd_common
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/cmd/common.py", line 32, in <module>
    from nova import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/utils.py", line 35, in <module>
    from openstack import connection
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import openstack.connection
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/connection.py", line 213, in <module>
    class Connection(six.with_metaclass(_meta.ConnectionMeta)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 856, in __new__
    return meta(name, resolved_bases, d)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/_meta.py", line 47, in __new__
    service_filter_class = _find_service_filter_class(service_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/_meta.py", line 113, in _find_service_filter_class
    service_filter_module = importlib.import_module(import_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/baremetal_introspection/baremetal_introspection_service.py", line 14, in <module>
    from openstack.baremetal_introspection.v1 import _proxy
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/baremetal_introspection/v1/_proxy.py", line 23, in <module>
    class Proxy(proxy.Proxy):
AttributeError: module 'openstack.proxy' has no attribute 'Proxy'
```